# OData date filter returns broken json

Tags: .net-core, odata

I'm writing a webapi with .net core 2.2 and odata. When I filter date field like this 
`http://localhost/odata/DATA?$filter=Period eq 2018-12-19T00:00:00Z`
it returns this

`{"@odata.context":"http://localhost/odata/$metadata#DATA","value":[`, a broken Json.

However when I filter with other fields i get value. For example: 
When I filter CompanyId field 
`http://localhost/odata/DATA?$filter=CompanyId eq 27&$top=1`

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost/odata/$metadata#DATA",
    "value": [
        {
            "CompanyId": 27,
            "Period": "2018-12-19T00:00:00Z",
            "ProposedVolume": null,
            "ProposedPrice": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand what's causing the problem. Here's my controller code:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("DATA")]
[Authorize]
public class DATAController : ODataController
{
    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<CompanyTrade> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var repo = new DBContext();
            return repo.CompanyTrade.AsQueryable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please lead me to a direction?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @mrtgnccn You need to write it like:
`http://localhost/odata/DATA?$filter=Period eq datetime'2018-12-19T00:00:00Z'`